# No rule to make target `NOTICE-TARGET-STATIC_LIBRARIES

Tags: java, android, static-libraries, rom

I'm compiling Omni 6.0.1 for MSM8226 (LG L90).
I've added a prebuilt lib from another ROM source to mine (They are the same) but I have this error now:
`make: *** No rule to make target NOTICE-TARGET-STATIC_LIBRARIES-lib_driver_cmd_qcwcn_intermediates' needed by /home/slimshadys/Omni/out/target/product/w7/obj/EXECUTABLES/hostapd_intermediates/LINKED/hostapd'. Stop."`

I think that I must include this prebuilt static library into .mk file but I don't know how to write it and also in which makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Create *Android.mk* in the folder which has the source and keeps the *.so* file and add below lines:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := lib_driver_cmd_qcwcn
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /lib/lib_driver_cmd_qcwcn.so
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: Ops, I was wrong. I don't have the .so file but I have only .o, .p, .a files.. 

Just like this:
`- driver_cmd_nl80211.p
- driver_cmd_nl80211.o
- lib_driver_cmd_qcwcn.a`
It's the same? I mean, instead of writing ".so", can I write ".p" and repeating this step also for .a and .o?